# Change an iframe height after clicking submit

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe that is pulling in a php page with a form, which the user submits and gets another php page of content (hosted on another domain). The original page content requires an iframe height of around 300px but the generated content page requires the iframe to be around 2300px in height.

Is there a way to set the iframe height to be 300px when the page first loads, but then change to 2300px after the user submits the form and gets the second page of content? I've tried several different solutions for this posted on this site but none have worked.

I do have access to the page that is being pulled in through the iframe as well, if that helps.

This is my iframe code:

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://example.com" style="height:300px;" width="100%"></iframe>
```

On http://example.com I tried this script:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").on('submit',function(){
        $('#iframe', window.parent.document).css({height:'2300px'});

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Show some your code and we see what don't work.

Comment: Listen the submit event and set `window.frameElement.height = '2300px';` in the handler. Though this will resize the iframe before a new page is loaded, but with cross-domain pages, this probably is your best bet.